# Powershell - Copy ADuser Direct Reports to Another User

Tags: powershell

Trying to find a way to copy direct reports from a manager in AD using powershell V4 to another manager.

I can get a list of direct reports using:

```
Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties directreports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports
```

But there is no -directreports property for the set-aduser cmdlet.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the `-Manager` property not be what you are looking for? You can set it with a `SamAccountName` or `DistinguishedName`

```
$manager = Get-ADUser auser -Properties manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager
Set-Aduser -Identity otheruser -Manager $manager
```

**Update from comments**

As I commonly do I misunderstood your post. The `directReports` attribute is set by the system. Similar to the relationship of `members` and `MemberOf` in AD `directReports` is the collection of all the users that have a particular manager set. In order to copy the direct reports from one manager to the next you should just have to set the manager for each user for a particular `directReport`. Example:

```
Get-Aduser oldManager -Properties directReports | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports | 
    Set-ADUser -Manager newManager
```

You might need to play with this a little depending on you needs but in it simplest form what happens is we take the `directreports` from the oldManager and expand them to get there Distinguishednames. That gets piped into `Set-Aduser` which will set all of those users manager to the new manager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Matt. The issue is that a manager may have 10+ direct reports. To achieve what you are suggesting, I could assign samaccount names to a variable and do a foreach loop against each name to change the manager name. I was hoping there was a quicker, easier way.

Comment: @Dan I lost sight of this answer. I am updating it now with what I think you need to do